# Disable service version detection

Tags: linux, nmap

`nmap` can be used to detect open ports and services associated with it. Also, we can use `-sV` flag to determine the service version.

Is there any way to disable this server version detection? A hacker can attack a system if he knows the version details.

On Ubuntu-20.04 e.g., following are the result for service version detection for the given range

```
SHW@system:~$ nmap -sV -p 631 localhost
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2022-05-16 18:11 IST
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00022s latency).
rDNS record for 127.0.0.1: view-localhost

PORT    STATE  SERVICE   VERSION
631/tcp open   ipp       CUPS 2.3   <== Version detected

Service detection performed. Please report any incorrect results 
at https://nmap.org/submit/.
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 7.58 seconds
```

Here, what changes shall I make on Ubuntu to block 631 port's service version?

Comment: which services are we talking about here? Because that detection works differently for different services, Some simply send the version of their software as read from a config file in the protocol that they implement, for others, `nmap` implements more or less complicated methods of infering the version from specific parts of the replies or from behaviour. Not a uniform thing!

Comment: We are talking in general. The above example is just for illustration. nmap probe the port to get the service information. I want to hide this service information.  I do not think that these versions information came from some config file

Comment: But: in general we can't talk about this. Because, as I explained above: it's not a general TCP/IP thing to supply such information. (have you really read my full comment above?)

Comment: Let me simplify it: What changes shall I make on my system so that anyone who scan the ports 631 of my machine, will not get version information?  I hope question is clear now.

Comment: so, we are talking about CUPS, in particular, right, not any other service that occupies that port?

Comment: Yes. As of now only CUPS. I will modify the question above

Answer (score 2):

You'll find that cups simply, by itself, happily delivers the version in the `<title>` attribute of the HTML page it delivers when you request `/` via HTTP on port 631.

That's read from the configured template file that your CUPS was delivered with – most probably something like `/usr/share/cups/www/index.html`. So, removing *this* avenue of getting the version string is rather trivial – just modify that configuration file :)

However, that's really just cosmetics – from the links in that file, even if you decided to rewrite it completely, one could very trivially infer that it's a CUPS (and not some other IPP server).

Furthermore, CUPS does exist to *fulfill a purpose*; the way it does that should probably be enough to correctly identify its version. Versions differ – that's why they're different versions – in such details. With not very much effort, someone could go through the CHANGELOGs/git history and figure out what of its endpoints to query to trigger responses that allow one to nail down the version.

This is the thing: any protocol that leaves even a modicum of freedom (and if it's only in e.g. timing, or number of ignored white space in responses!)  will allow different implementations (and for this, different versions are different implementations) to behave differently, *observably so*. And from that you can infer the version.

The only version around that would be a protocol that is *very* minimal and constrained, and only allows for *exactly* one behaviour. (And if you have such a protocol, it's likely the server offering an implementation of that would also not see any new versions.) These protocols are very rare, and IPP certainly is quite the opposite: Flexible transport (a complex HTTP-based protocol!), with flexible capabilities with detection and flexible replies. No two implementations of that protocol will ever be the same!

---

**TL;DR**: in general, you can't. Especially for protocols as complex as IPP (which is what CUPS offers on that port), you stand no realistic chance of completely obfuscating the version; the only choice you'd have is re-implementing significant parts of CUPS differently. And then you'd basically just have made a different software out of it, and get your own detectable version, and your own security issues.

---

I've got some issues with this statement:

> A hacker can attack a system if he knows the version details.

Really not the way this works. An *admin* can fix the system if he knows what services need upgrading, but the attacker just wants to exploit a vulnerability if it's there. The attacker doesn't care about the version at all – only about the presence of the vulnerability, which is usually about as hard to figure out as the version number, so typically, attackers just try out a couple of known vulnerabilities rather than trying to figure out the version of the software used – which might or might not already be patched to not contain the vulnerability!

So, hiding the version really does little good. If I know that the CUPS I'm talking to has a double-free vulnerability that I can maybe exploit by triggering a local scan for printers, then I will just try to tigger that – it's just a request.